# Missing <component>.html_script_0.js files in Polymer build using the CLI tool

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having problems running the `polymer build` command of the polymer CLI, it gives me the following feedback:

[image: windows cmd showing error message while looking for index.html]

and neither of my built folders (bundled or unbundled) have the javascript files. The build process places `<script>` tag with the `src` of a javascript file in the place of my javascript code, but this files are not being generated.

[image: chrome developer tool showing .js files missing]

I don't know if both errors are related, but I don't know what can I do to generate the `<component>.html_script_0.js` files.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and saw that there were [several](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/191) [issues](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/184) reporting it.

It seems a [fix has been already merged](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/pull/199) and is part of [v0.9.0](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/compare/v0.8.0...master) but I'm not completely sure if the fix is up on npm just yet.